# Multiple queries with DBExtensions SqlBuilder

Tags: ado.net, dbextensions

When using the [SqlBuilder](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/wiki/SqlBuilder-Tutorial) class of [DBExtensions](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions), is it possible to build multiple select statements that are executed in a single round trip?

Something along the lines of:

```
select t1.* from Table1 t1 where t1.Foo = 'Bar 1';
select t2.* from Table2 t2 where t2.Foo = 'Bar 2';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the building part, you can do:

```
var query1 = SQL
   .SELECT("t1.*")
   .FROM("Table1 t1")
   .WHERE("t1.Foo = {0}", "Bar 1");

var query2 = SQL
   .SELECT("t2.*")
   .FROM("Table2 t2")
   .WHERE("t2.Foo = {0}", "Bar 2");

var batchQuery = SqlBuilder.JoinSql(";", query1, query2);
```

About execution, I have no idea if your ADO.NET provider supports batch SELECT queries, maybe you want to do a UNION query instead?

Comment: Thank you - exactly what I was looking for! And yes, my provider (SQL Server) allows for multiple chained queries like this.